# DialogFragment created twice after orientation change

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

Hi I'm currently trying to implement a tutorial dialog wherein one dialog will appear after the other one is dismissed. Now everything works just fine but after the orientation changes the dialog is then recreated twice. And more than that after I dismissed all the dialog and then try to change orientation once again the dialog will reappear which is annoying. Here's my code so far:

```
public class TutorialOne extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_tutorial1, container, false);

        Button next = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        if(isRemoving()) {
            TutorialTwo tutorialTwo = new TutorialTwo();
            tutorialTwo.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "tutorial_2");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        // request a window without the title
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        return dialog;
    }

}
```

Did I missed out on something here?

Comment: have you create dialog from onCreate() ? or can you post your activity code where you create dialog ?

Comment: Hi, nope I create the dialog on click from my drawer list using the same .show method you see on the onDetach method.

Comment: Try to check if your dialog already added you fragment manager then simply show it otherwise create new instance of your dialog fragment.

Comment: Although I'm not sure as well why does my dialog is being recreated on orientation change even though it should already been dismissed.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are attaching the second dialog in the onDetach() callback and not in the OnClickListener where you dismiss the dialog fragment? You should also post some code related to the portion of code from where this dialogs are spawned.

Comment: well since at first I have 3 dialogs which appears one after another. Now I tried to convert it into one dialog but still the problem happens. I even tried to change it into a transparent ActionbarActivity and do some intent on click of item on drawer but strange enough the problem still happens.

Comment: see my answer, i hope its works for you

Comment: If those dialogs appear even if after you dismiss them(and change the configuration) then the problem is most likely due to the way you start those dialog fragments. You should avoid doing what the accepted answer recommends as curioustechizen already pointed out.

Comment: You shoud use the `dismiss()` method of the `DialogFragment` instead of the `Dialog`, to enable it to handle it's state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improvement

Some device configurations can change during runtime (such as screen orientation, keyboard availability, and language). When such a change occurs, Android restarts the running Activity (onDestroy() is called, followed by onCreate()). The restart behavior is designed to help your application adapt to new configurations by automatically reloading your application with alternative resources that match the new device configuration.

There are two way to handle this

1. [Retain an object during a configuration change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject)

   ```
   Allow your activity to restart when a configuration changes, but carry a stateful object to the new instance of your activity.
   ```
2. [Handle the configuration change yourself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

   ```
   Prevent the system from restarting your activity during certain configuration changes, but receive a callback when the
   configurations do change, so that you can manually update your
   activity as necessary.
   ```

   according 2 ways if you dont want recreate your activity and handle config change manually, [configchanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) add below manifest of project

   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

Now, when one of these configurations change, MyActivity does not restart. Instead, the MyActivity receives a call to onConfigurationChanged()

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Note: Handling runtime change not suggest by [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: Wow, this thing works on my dialog but a problem happens since I need to handle configuration change so that I can update the columns of my grid on my main activity.

Comment: see my edited ans, and its works for you then mark as right, thanks

Comment: but this won't target to the specified resources that I need to use on landscape view and I need to manually set it up. Anyways, so far this is great. I'll try to make use of it and get back to you soon as I can.

Comment: r u using custom layout for dialog form layout folder

Comment: then create two folder 1.layout-port, 2.layout-land and create xml for ported and landscape mode, it takes automatically for res when orientation change

Comment: I've already done those steps. in fact I have two folders for handling values in normal and landscape which are values and values-land folder. inside that folder contains different dimensions and integer for column count in my gridview but it doesn't make use of it on orientation change.

Comment: use port and landscape folder not normal, and remove xml from normal, clean & build project, then run try this may be its works for you.

Comment: for now I just manually changed it. since I've already managed to keep my orientation changes minimal so it works for me. Thanks!

Comment: This solves the problem short term but it introduces several other issues. [This document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) on Android Developers site explains why. " This technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and is not recommended for most applications."

Comment: I agree with that. I guess since this somewhat solves my problem for now which is why I marked it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26709740/570930) which is the currently accepted answer, works but it will create problems for you in the future. Read [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) on Android developers documentation for details. In particular, the "Handling the Configuration Change Yourself" section says:

> **Note:** Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much more difficult to use alternative resources, because the system does not automatically apply them for you. This technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and is not recommended for most applications.

Coming to your original problem, I think you should just move the code for displaying the second dialog from your `onDetach()`  to your `onClick()`.

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getDialog().dismiss();
        showTutorial2Dialog();
    }
});

private void showTutorial2Dialog(){
    TutorialTwo tutorialTwo = new TutorialTwo();
    tutorialTwo.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "tutorial_2");
}
```

You might have to play with the order of the calls to `getDialog().dismiss()` and `showTutorial2Dialog()` to get this working though.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) says

> `void dismiss()`
>
> Dismiss the fragment and its dialog.

Instead of `getDialog().dismiss()` call `dismiss()` as this will destroy both `Dialog` AND the `Fragment` so it won't recreate.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code to DialogFragment :

```
@Override
 public void onDestroyView() {
     if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
         getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
     super.onDestroyView();
 }
```

You need to override `onPrepareDialog`and keep a CONSTANT ID

- Implement the onCreateDialog method
- Implement the onPrepareDialog
  method
- Keep a constant with the custom dialog ID
- Call the showDialog method to display the dialog
- Call the removeDialog or  dismissDialog methods to remove the dialog from the screen

[Refer this to get more info](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/07/creating-an-android-dialog-and-maintaining-its-state-on-screen-orientation-change/)

Comment: Tried it already, still two dialogs are created on orientation change and even if dismissed when orientation change happens the dialog shows up again.

Comment: can't you disable orientation change ?

Comment: I can't. I mean it is a requirement for my project. :(

Comment: Oh.. :( have a [look to this blog](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/07/creating-an-android-dialog-and-maintaining-its-state-on-screen-orientation-change/) ..You might find your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement DialogInterface.OnClickListener and DialogInterface.OnCancelListener :

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
       // Your "onClick" code here

       this.dismiss();  // only if you close dialog after "onClick"
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
        // Your "onCancel" code here

        this.dismiss(); // also handle click outside the dialog
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this inside your onCreateView method:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        dismiss()
    }
```